# Recognize if google chrome extension is installed

Tags: c#

Is there a way to determine if a specific extension is installed in Chrome with C# code?

I have only found JS options here in Stack Overflow.

I have tried to look for relevant files under %AppData% but there weren't.

Note: The requirment is to develop it with .Net 3.5.

Comment: What *kind* of application are you making? A website that needs to detect the extension in the browser that navigates your site? A desktop program that needs to analyze Chrome?

Comment: The second option. Analyze chrome from desktop app.

Comment: The extension is stored in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\<extension id>`, assuming the default profile only.

Comment: I was lloking there. Unfortunately, The specific extension is not there.

Comment: Stupid question but always worth checking. Do you have the extension installed?

Comment: Yep, installed and working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. The problem was that the extension was loaded in developer mode from an unpacked folder. Therefore it wasn't copied to the %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\ directory.

So to look for an extension you have to first look in the mentioned path for manifest.json file and after that:

```
Load: %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\preferences (it's a file)
Deserialize the json content.
iterate objects with "path" property.
Go to each path and open the manifest.json file
```

Hope it will help somebody.